# multiple fields in a group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

After much hunting I'm forced to ask:  All I want to do is add a field to a group statement.  I have a simple little query:

```
SELECT product_id, count(*) 
FROM uut_result 
WHERE start_date_time = '2016-06-16 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY product_id ASC;
```

So, for example, I want:

```
SELECT product_id, reception_date, count(*)
from uut_result
group by product_id
```

Which would give us:

```
KL2483    2016-07-14    48
```

that's all it is, and all I want to do is pull in one extra field in the select statement.  But MySQL won't let me have more than two fields. Is there a simple way to get around that?

Comment: Show us sample table data, the expected result. And the query that goes wrong.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: that is weird - I go off, check an answer, it works beautifully, I come back here to accept it and it looks like it's been deleted. Shame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pull in another field by using an aggregation function:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(othercol), count(*) 
FROM uut_result 
WHERE start_date_time = '2016-06-16 00:00:00' 
GROUP BY product_id 
ORDER BY product_id ASC;
```

Your server must have the mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` set (perhaps via the `ANSI` mode).  Otherwise, MySQL would allow additional columns in the `SELECT`.

Comment: it's happened to me, there's clearly a troll about.  Have a deserved upvote

Answer (score 3):

One way to add an additional column to your result set is to place your current `GROUP BY` into a *subquery*, and then join it back to the original table:

```
SELECT t1.product_id, t1.reception_date, t2.product_count
FROM uut_result t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) AS product_count
    FROM uut_result 
    WHERE start_date_time = '2016-06-16 00:00:00' 
    GROUP BY product_id 
) t2
    ON t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

Comment: This returns lots of additional rows that, presumably, the OP does not want.

Comment: It's too clever for this query but I've saved it anyway for later ones.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

The answer that worked best for me looks to have been deleted. Shame. For the record I can have the extra field I need as long as I group by it:

```
SELECT age, height, max(goal_average) FROM players 

GROUP BY age, height <-- it's this second grouping that allows the height field.

etc.
```

Helped me anyway, I just wish I could give credit where it's due.